# Sharing a wish list button is missing in my wish list magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, wishlist, addtowishlist, share-wishlist

On the my wishlist page, I am not able to see the Share wish list button in the Magento 2 frontend. Previously it worked but now that button is not appearing suddenly.

Help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Its because you have reached the limit of Max Emails Allowed to be Sent Threshold Value
- The default value of Max Emails Allowed to be Sent is 10
- We can change the value in Admin Panel -> Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Wish List

  - In Share Options Tab

    - Change the Max Emails Allowed and refresh the cache